# How to calculate an effect size and confidence interval after running a Generalised Estimating Equation?

Tags: r, generalized-linear-model, generalized-estimating-equations

I am doing a randomised controlled trial and I need to use a GEE model for my statistical analysis.

I have two groups (intervention and control) and I collect injured subjects every month (during 7 months) across a whole season (either injured or not. i.e. injury prevalence), and in the end I want to compare both groups throughout the season. I have read two papers that use GEE with similar study designs compared to my study (Harøy et al. 2017: https://doi.org/10.1136/bjsports-2017-098937 and Åkerlund et al. 2022: https://doi.org/10.1007/s00167-021-06644-2), although they use SPSS for statistical analysis, also idk how to perform GEE there.

I started reading the documents from the "gee" package and end up running this code:

```r
migee <- gee(Injury ~ GRUPO * Tiempo, family = poisson(link = "log"), 
           data = GEE_trial, corstr = "exchangeable", id = id)
```

"Injury" is a dichotomous variable that means either injured player or not
"GRUPO" is the group, either control or intervention
"Tiempo" is each month
GEE_trial is the dataframe
"id" is a number assigned to each subject

I used log poisson and an exchangeable correlation structure since I read in the aforementioned papers that they used this format. Although I am not sure whether this is properly performed or not.

After running the analysis and the "summary" function, various coefficients appeared (note that i only run the analysis with data from three months instead of the entire season) with standard errors and z-scores.
Coefficients:

```r
                 Estimate Naive S.E.    Naive z Robust S.E.   Robust z
(Intercept)    -2.1400662  0.6492832 -3.2960444   0.6642112 -3.2219666
GRUPO1          1.1415373  0.7362179  1.5505427   0.7289733  1.5659522
Tiempo2         0.6931472  0.7952062  0.8716571   0.7952062  0.8716571
Tiempo3         0.6931472  0.7952062  0.8716571   0.7952062  0.8716571
GRUPO1:Tiempo2 -1.9459101  1.0836834 -1.7956445   1.0816408 -1.7990354
GRUPO1:Tiempo3 -1.5404450  1.0167826 -1.5150191   1.0016388 -1.5379247
```

I read that by exponentiating the "GRUPO1" coefficient, I would get the Odds ratio, since this is the effect size that I need to present in the paper. However, in the mentioned papers they present the Odds ratio (or Rate ratio (Åkerlund 2022) with the confidence interval.

First, I have no idea whether I have performed the analysis properly.
Second, if correct, how can i calculate the confidence interval for this effect size (Odds ratio or Rate ratio)?

Third, if incorrect, how can I perform the analysis correctly?

Answer (score 1):

We can't help with the "is this correct" because that is predicated on the scientific question at hand and something only you and subject-matter experts can determine. If you are naive to statistics and their role in your analysis, I suggest you consult a statistician within the institution from where you are working on your PhD to guide you. These types of discussion are also off-topic for stack overflow (you may consider [Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com))

As far as the *objective, coding-related question* goes, I dont believe `gee` objects can use typical functions to gather the confidence intervals (ie, `confint()`). However, you can calculate the Wald confidence interval directly using the results of the model.

You didnt provide data, so using this reproducible data:

```
set.seed(123)
n <- 1e3
GEE_trial <- data.frame(Injury = sample(0:1, n, replace = TRUE),
                 id = factor(LETTERS[1:5]),
                 GRUPO =  factor(sample(0:1, n, replace = TRUE)),
                 Tiempo = factor(sample(1:3,  n, replace = TRUE)))
```

You can run the model (`migee`), extract the results (`mdlresults`), then calculate the confidence intervals and organize the results in a data frame (`finalres`):

```
# model
migee <- gee::gee(Injury ~ GRUPO * Tiempo,
                  family = poisson(link = "log"),
                  data = GEE_trial,
                  corstr = "exchangeable",
                  id = id)

# 95% Wald confidence interval
ci <- 0.95
xx <- qnorm((1 + ci) / 2)

# final results
finalres <- data.frame(param = rownames(mdlresults),
                       est = mdlresults$Estimate,
                       lwr =  mdlresults$Estimate - xx * mdlresults$Robust.S.E.,
                       upr = mdlresults$Estimate + xx * mdlresults$Robust.S.E.)
```

Output

```
# > finalres
#            param         est         lwr         upr
# 1    (Intercept) -0.79094492 -0.96054071 -0.62134914
# 2         GRUPO1  0.14851284 -0.07233009  0.36935577
# 3        Tiempo2  0.07898841 -0.15237451  0.31035133
# 4        Tiempo3  0.12337459 -0.09494036  0.34168953
# 5 GRUPO1:Tiempo2 -0.24411386 -0.56936113  0.08113342
# 6 GRUPO1:Tiempo3 -0.12646163 -0.42464761  0.17172435
```